# Using jsonb_array_elements in sqlalchemy select_from and join

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy ORM and trying to figure out how to produce a PostgreSQL query like the following:

```
SELECT resources.*
  FROM histories, jsonb_array_elements_text(histories.reported_resources) as report_resource_name
  JOIN resources ON resources.resource_name = report_resource_name
 WHERE histories.id = :id
```

So far I got this:

```
query = (
    select([
        Resource
    ])
    .select_from(
        History, 
        func.jsonb_array_elements(History.reported_resources).alias('report_resource_name'))
    .join(Resource, Resource.resource_name == text('report_resource_name'))
    .where(History.id = 1)
)
```

But the error says:

> InvalidRequestError: Can't determine which FROM clause to join from, there are multiple FROMS which can join to this entity. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explicit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.

How can I join the resources table ON the `jsonb_array_elements` result in `.select_from()` using SQLAlchemey?

Minimum model table and input data like following:

```
class History(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'histories'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    reported_resources = Column(JSONB) 

class Resource(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'resources'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    resource_name = Column(String)

Resource
id | resource_name
--------
1  | machine1
2  | machine2
3  | operator1
4  | operator4

History
id | reported_resources
-------
1  | ['machine2', 'operator4']
```

Comment: You could just use raw SQL? It's the source of tuuth anyway. ORMs are just obfuscation layers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fluid with the ORM dialect, but it should help to rewrite your SQL statement as:

```sql
SELECT resources.*
FROM   histories
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(histories.reported_resources) AS rr(report_resource_name)
JOIN   resources ON resources.resource_name = rr.report_resource_name
WHERE  histories.id = :id
```

(The `LATERAL` keyword being optional in this case.)

See:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/167201/3684)
- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: @python_user: Yes, `CROSS JOIN` is equivalent to `[INNER] JOIN ... ON true`. The only (obvious) difference is `SELECT resources.*` vs. `SELECT resources.id, ...`